# What is Hup singing in jail?

Tags: languages, dark-crystal, dark-crystal-age-of-resistance

Hup singing in jail was one of my favourite scenes from the Age of Resistance series (episode 4). I'm learning what I can about the podling language, and as such I'd like to know what the song translates to (assuming that it does have a translation). Given that J.M. Lee created a whole language for the Podlings in the TV series I would be surprised if it doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The song Hup sings is a Podling Funeral Song, as described on this [Podling language page](https://darkcrystal.fandom.com/wiki/Podling_language).

The page cites *Lee, J.M (2020), Songs of the Seven Gelfling Clans, Penguin Young Readers Licenses, p. 51* and gives the lyrics in the original Podling:

> Tindyebo Bekua Staba doga alori
> Shyata-oyo zeshaba aduma doda avi
> Yamda bi kiraba Vapa So shi
> Dze Aslampia'pida ya utomshi
> Boka babi, yamda shoshi ashao
> Ada bao temar mots nyotyano
> "Yeta'pida soraro?" bao temar'ashai
> Aslampia shyayo adado vatai
> "Apada arwe shi. Apadido dana
> Aslam mala-ga zagazaba ya Thra"

And the translation:

> Within the Endless Forest I wandered
> I met a creature dressed in bone white
> Its eyes were bright like the Silver Sea
> I knew it was Death come for me
> I fell to my knees in front of him and cried
> Still he didn't listen to my sad request
> "Why me?" I asked in a tearful voice
> He sighed before he replied
> "I'm merely a servant performing my duty
> It is Thra that is calling you home"

Which is, to me, almost as beautiful to read as hearing Hup sing it on the show.

---

If you want to follow Hup and sing along, we hear him start singing on the third line at, continues to the fourth before restarting at the beginning (it's partially unclear due to the fizgiggs and the whooshing fire). He's interrupted by the guards on the word *ashao* (end of line 5), before belting out the next two lines (6 and 7) in defiance. He's spooked part way through line 6 on *bao temar'ashai*

Here is a rough subtitled version I made: